# Make a click event happen X amount of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

I'm trying to make a click event happen X amount of times depending on the result of some maths. There are multiple rows with buttons that have the button I need pressing so i've got it looking through as you can see. However how do I make it so that the `$(obj).click();` is fired `numClickVar` times?

```
$("#bookOutAll2").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".ControlButtonPLUS").each(function(i, obj) {
        var data = $(this).closest("tr").find(".bookedOutText").text();
        var data2 = $(this).closest("tr").find(".requestedQty").text();
        var numClickVar = data2 - data ;

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (numClickVar > 0) {
                // **** needs to happen numClickVar of times *****
                $(obj).click();
            }
        }, 450 * i);
    });
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on what the logic is doing I'd suggest you calculate the result based on `numClickVar` and update the UI once, instead of creating N number of dummy requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what iteration is for

```
for (var i=0; i<numClickVar; i++) {
    $(obj).click();
}
```

you create a loop that is executed `n` times, and place your code inside it.

If you wanted a timeout to go with that, you could use recursive function calls

```
(function fn(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(obj).click();            
        if ( i < numClickVar ) fn(++i);
    },450);
})(0);
```